# Access Value in For Loop Twice Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I'm trying to access a column value twice in a for loop. I really tried to figure this out on my own before asking but Oracle and/or PL/SQL isn't my strong suit. The first time the value is accessed in the line it is there. The second time it just comes up as empty single parenthesis ''. Any help would be appreciated.

```
BEGIN

   FOR t IN (SELECT object_name, object_type FROM all_objects WHERE owner='USER' AND object_type IN ('TABLE','VIEW','PROCEDURE','FUNCTION','PACKAGE','PACKAGE BODY','LOB','SEQUENCE','SYNONYM','TYPE')) LOOP

     IF t.object_type IN ('SYNONYM') THEN
       --the second time t.object_name is called in line below it is empty.
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE OR REPLACE SYNONYM NEW_USER.'||t.object_name||' FOR USER.'||t.object_name||'';

     END IF;

   END LOOP;

END;

/
```

Comment: This is why I always generate the statement into a variable and then do execute intimidate variable name. When problems occur I can output the the actual statement attempted. For this one however; Do you actually have a schema name USER? Necessary if your cursor had results - very bad plan . More to the point do you have a schema 'NEW_USER' as that is where you attempt to create the synonym. The error message implies the schema 'NEW_USER' does not exist. Had the value of t_object_name been null (empty) you would get error "ORA-00995: missing or invalid synonym identifier".

Answer (score 0):

Using variable:

```
DECLARE
   t_name VARCHAR2(30);

BEGIN

   FOR t IN (SELECT object_name, object_type FROM all_objects 
             WHERE owner='USER' 
               AND object_type IN ('TABLE','VIEW','PROCEDURE'
                                   ,'FUNCTION','PACKAGE','PACKAGE BODY'
                                   ,'LOB','SEQUENCE','SYNONYM','TYPE')) 
LOOP
     t_name:=DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_NAME(t.object_name);
     IF t.object_type IN ('SYNONYM') THEN

       --the second time t.object_name is called in line below it is empty.
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE OR REPLACE SYNONYM NEW_USER.'||t_name||' FOR USER.'||t_name||'';
     END IF;
   END LOOP;
END;
 /
```

Comment: It shouldn't, assigning to a variable is a most obvious way to be sure you get same value. Let me check.

Comment: @RobertHarvey No it isn't https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=da47440ddbaf79de85833506ba21730f My other guesses are, identifier needs qouting because it contains special characters/nul character(0x0) maybe

Comment: This didn't work. I still received the error saying ORA-01917: user or role '' does not exist
ORA-06512: at line 10

Comment: @R.Lansing Post the output of `SELECT`. I guess it contains space/tab/anything special for that specific row.

Comment: I don't believe there are any special characters for the synonym names. They should be just TABLE_NAME format without the schema. Let me check.

Comment: Anyway you could try `DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_NAME(t.object_name)`

Comment: I checked the output of the select for the values and nothing unusual. No spaces, or tabs or characters, just the standard TABLE_NAME format.

Comment: `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'CREATE OR REPLACE SYNONYM NEW_USER.'||t_name||' FOR USER.'||t_name||'');`  -- is it correct statement?